# Firebase 9 getDocs(qry) not returning

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

so i have been working on project using firebase(firestore) and while doing so, i faced this problem, which is that `getDocs(qry)` is hung, and neither resolving nor throwing an error.

```
import {
    collection,
    addDoc,
    getFirestore,
    DocumentData,
    getDocs,
    query,
    orderBy,
    Query,
    limit,
    startAfter,
    DocumentSnapshot,
} from "firebase/firestore";

const db = getFirestore();
let last: DocumentSnapshot;
const modelsRef = collection(db, "models");

export const getModels = async (initial: boolean): Promise<DocumentData[]> => {
    let results: DocumentData[] = [];
    let qry: Query<DocumentData>;
    if (initial) {
        qry = query(modelsRef, orderBy("createdAt", "desc"), limit(8));
    } else {
        if (last) {
            qry = query(
                modelsRef,
                orderBy("createdAt", "desc"),
                startAfter(last),
                limit(8)
            );
        } else {
            return results;
        }
    }
    console.log("before");
    const documentSnapshots = await getDocs(qry); // flow control hang here...
    console.log("after");
    documentSnapshots.forEach((doc) => {
        return results.push(doc.data());
    });
    last = documentSnapshots.docs[documentSnapshots.docs.length - 1];
    console.log(initial);
    return results;
};
```

Comment: Where is `modelsRef` declared also what is `last`?

Comment: @Dharmaraj sorry, I forgot to add it, I edited the post now.

Comment: So you are saying it won't log `after` ? Try removing `return` from that `forEach`. Only `push()` statement should do.

Comment: @Dharmaraj yes, the before message is printed to the console, but the after not.

Comment: Nothing changed after removing the return.

Comment: Can you use `getDocs(qry).then(() => console.log("fetched data").catch(e => console.log(e))` and see if there is any error ?

Comment: i wrote it just like this ```getDocs(query(modelsRef, orderBy("createdAt", "desc"), limit(8)))
  .then((docs) => console.log(docs))
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));``` and it threw no errors.

Comment: Can you share the code where you are calling this function from? By chance is this available in a github repo so issue can be replicated?

Comment: Sure, here is the link [github](https://github.com/medi11/rachmat). check the index file.

Comment: Was this issue solved?